# python set command produces unequal results in different execution order

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why do the following commands produce unequal results?  I would think they would be the same.

```
>>> len(sorted(set(w.lower()) for w in text1))
260819
>>> len(sorted(w.lower() for w in set(text1)))
19317
```

Comment: The `set` function can be used to filter out duplicate values.  So `set(text1)` filters out duplicate words, whereas `set(w.lower())` filters out duplicate lower-case letters.  This is why you have different results.

Answer (score 0):

`len(sorted(set(w.lower()) for w in text1))` is equal to `len(text1)` because it produces one set for each element in `text1`.

`len(sorted(w.lower() for w in set(text1)))` is equal to the number of different items in `text1`, because it produces one string for each string in `set(text1)`.

For instance, if `text1` is `['Alpha', 'beta', 'beta']` then

`sorted(set(w.lower()) for w in text1)` is a list of three sets:

```
[{'p', 'l', 'h', 'a'}, {'b', 'e', 'a', 't'}, {'b', 'e', 'a', 't'}]
```

Whereas `sorted(w.lower() for w in set(text1))` is a list of two strings:

```
['alpha', 'beta']
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting different results because `set` function can be used to filter out duplicate values.

Per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) (bold mine):

> A set object is an unordered collection of **distinct** hashable objects.
>   Common uses include membership testing, **removing duplicates from a
>   sequence** ...

So `set(text1)` filters out duplicate **words**, whereas `set(w.lower())` filters out duplicate lower-case **letters**. This is why you have different results.